# The diophantine eq. $x^4 +y^4 +1=z^2$

Tags: diophantine-equations, nt.number-theory

> This question is an exact duplicate of the question
>
> [Does the equation $x^4+y^4+1=z^2$ have a non-trivial solution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16887/)
>
> posted by [Tito Piezas III](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/4781/tito-piezas-iii) on [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

The background of this question is this: Fermat proved that the equation, $$x^4 +y^4=z^2$$
has no solution in the positive integers.  If we consider the near-miss, $$x^4 +y^4-1=z^2$$
then this has plenty (in fact, an infinity, as it can be solved by a Pell equation). But J. Cullen, by exhaustive search, found that the other near-miss, $$x^4 +y^4 +1=z^2$$
has none with $0 < x,y < 10^6$  .

Does the third equation really have none at all, or are the solutions just enormous?

Comment: If I haven't messed up, x and y both are multiples of 10.  My feeling is that one more congruence (besides 5 and 8) might show there are no solutions.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.04.15

Comment: Also, y=1, z=x^2 is one family of solutions to the previous near-miss.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.04.15

Comment: The question was also posted in January at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16887/does-the-equation-x4y41-z2-have-a-non-trivial-solution

Comment: To find a solution mod $p$, you just need $x^4+y^4+1$ to be a quadratic residue.  There are many choices for $x$ and $y$, and half the numbers mod $p$ are quadratic residues, so this must almost always be possible.  If we have a mod $p$ solution, then to improve it to a $p$-adic solution, we need to find a $p$-adic square root of $u=(1+x^4+y^4)/z^2$.  Here $u=1\pmod{p}$, so the square root will always exist if $p>2$.  We can find a $2$-adic solution in the same way provided that we start with a mod $4$ solution, such as $(2,2,1)$.  Thus, there are probably solutions mod $n$ for all $n$.

Comment: There are certainly plenty of *rational* solutions.  Elkies (Math. Comp. vol. 51, no. 184 (1988), pp. 825&ndash;835) showed that the equation $A^4+B^4+C^4=D^4$ has infinitely many integer solutions; by a well-known theorem we can't have $C=0$, so then $(A/C,B/C,D^2/C^2) gives a rational solution to the equation above.

Comment: It might not be unreasonable to look for a Brauer-Manin obstruction to the existence of integral points here.

Comment: There is no solution with $0 < x \le y \le 2\cdot 10^7$. If this is not solved in reasonable time I might try to write less trivial code and push the limit further. This limit was reached over-night with one 1.3GHz core on my laptop.

Comment: @known google: On the face of it, a Brauer-Manin argument isn't going to work here because of the trivial solutions $(0,0,\pm 1)$.

Comment: $x=y$ looks difficult. The known solution to $z^2 - 2 x^4 = \pm 1$ in positive integers is $z = 239, x = 13.$  Ljunggren 1966, Mordell 1964, both J. London Math. Soc., there are at most two solutions, none known, to $z^2 - 2 x^4 =  1.$

Comment: Infiniteness of rational solutions is easy to obtain from the identity
$$(xy)^4 + (xz)^4 + (yz)^4 = (z^4 - x^2y^2)^2$$
which holds for Pythagorean triples $(x,y,z)$ with $x^2+y^2=z^2$.

Comment: @Will Jagy: According to Sierpinsky's "Elementary Theory of Numbers", the equation $2x^4 + 1 = z^2$ is insolvable in integers, while the equation $2x^4 - 1 = z^2$ has exactly two solutions in positive integers: (1,1) and (13,239).

Comment: The first statement of Max above appears also as problem $P_67^2$  (the exponent means `solved`) in page 114 of Sierpinski's ``A Selection of Problems in the Theory of Numbers` (from 1964).

Comment: Is the `second` statement...

Comment: 
According to Mordell's `Diophantine Equations` the complete solution in integers
of the related equation
$$
x^2+y^2+1=z^2
$$

is

$$
dx = 2X_1X_3, dy = 2X_2X_3, d = X_3^2-X_1^2-X_2^2, dz = X_3^2+X_1^2+X_2^2
$$

where $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are integers with
$$
gcd(X_1,X_2,X_3)=1
$$
and the positive integer $d>0$  is chosen such that
$$
gcd(x,y,z)=1.
$$


Comment: @Luis: What do you meant saying "$d$ is chosen"? You've already said that $d=X_3^2-X_1^2-X_2^2$ so that for fixed $X_1, X_2, X_3$, the value of $d$ is "chosen" automatically.

Comment: @Max: You are right !; hope these formulae be useful anyway.

Comment: Max, thanks for the reference. I played around later with $y = 2x,$ then $y = 3 x$ and the like, mostly because it let me use continued fractions for $z^2 - (k^4 + 1) w^2 = \pm 1,$ then hope $w$ is a square. Not really any better than $k=1.$

Comment: Why is my question (asked in a Mathstackexchange [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16887/) in Jan 2011) copied word-for-word by this poster?

Comment: Link to 2013 meta.MO post about this apparent case of plagiarism: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/729/somebody-copied-my-question-from-mathstackexchange-word-for-word (Please vote up for visibility)

Answer (score 9):

Didn't find any solutions with $1 \leq y \leq 7.9 \cdot 10^7$ and no restriction on $x,z$ in about 17 hours on 1 core.

Here is the search:

Per several discussions and arguments $\mod {20}$ both $x,y$ are divisible by $10$.

Rewrite as $$ y^4 + 1 = z^2 - x^4 $$

The RHS is a difference of two squares with the additional restriction the second square must be fourth power, so the algorithm uses a single loop, write $(10y_1)^4+1$ as a difference of two squares (in all possible ways) and checks for fourth power.

Answer (score 5):

Let take a look to the special case:
$$
y=ax
$$
where $a$ is a fixed nonzero integer.  When $a=1$ was already observed by Max Alexseyev that there is no solution.
Since
$$
x^4+y^4+(x+y)^4=2(x^2+xy+y^2)^2
$$
the equation $x^4+y^4+1=z^2$ can then be written:
$$
X^2 -DY^4 =1
$$
with
$$
X=z, Y=x,  D = a^4+1.
$$

(Or, more simply, we get this also directly from the original equation...).

Observe now that 
the equation
$$
a^4+1=w^2
$$
has no integer solution $w$.
See e.g.,  Corollary in page 17 of Mordell's `Diophantine Equations`.

Then it follows from the paper of Togbe et al. below that there are at most $2$ positive solutions
$x,z$ of the equation.

Togbe, A.; Voutier, P. M.; Walsh, P. G.(3-OTTW)
Solving a family of Thue equations with an application to the equation $x^2-Dy^4=1$.
Acta Arith. 120 (2005), no. 1, 39–58.
11D59 (11D25)

Let $D$ be a positive nonsquare integer. The authors study the Diophantine equation $X^2-DY^4=1$ in positive integers $X$ and $Y$ and refine a theorem of W. Ljunggren [Skr. Norske Vid.-Akad. Oslo I 1936, no. 12, 1--73; Zbl 0016.00802]. Let $(T_1,U_1)$ be the smallest integer solution to the Pell equation $X^2-DY^2=1$. For $k\ge 1$, let $T_k+U_k\sqrt D={(T_1+U_1\sqrt D)^k}$ represent all positive integer solutions to the Pell equation. The authors prove:
   There are at most two positive integer solutions $(X,Y)$ to the equation $X^2-DY^4=1$. If two solutions $Y_1 <Y_2$ exist, then $Y_1^2=U_1$ and $Y_2^2=U_2$, except only if $D=1785$ or $D=16\cdot 1785$, in which case $Y_1^2=U_1$ and $Y_2^2=U_4$. If only one positive integer solution $(X,Y)$ exists, then $Y^2=U_l$ where $U_1=lv^2$ for some squarefree integer $l$, and either $l=1$, $l=2$, or $l=p$ for some prime $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$.
   The problem is reduced to solving the family of Thue equations $x^4+4tx^3y-6tx^2y^2-4t^2xy^3+t^2y^4=t_0^2$, where $t_0$ divides $t$ and $t_0\le \sqrt t$, for a positive integer $t$. However, it is not required to solve this family completely, but only for solutions whose quotient $x/y$ is near to $\beta^{(3)}$ or $\beta^{(4)}$, where $\beta^{(j)}$, $j=1,\dots,4$, denote the roots of the univariate polynomial corresponding to the Thue equation in a particular order defined in the paper. For these two roots, an effective measure of irrationality can be proved by Thue's hypergeometric method.
Reviewed by Clemens Heuberger

Comment: It looks like we always have $T_1=2a^4+1$ and $U_1=2a^2$. Thus $U_1$ is not a square, and we further have $l=2$ and $U_l=4a^2(2a^4+1)$ which is neither a square. Hence, there are no integer solutions to $X^2−(a^4+1)Y^4=1$.

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer but just a probabilistic (i.e. heuristic) argument which is too long for a comment.

I want to argue that the equation $x^4+y^4+1=z^2$ is likely to have non-trivial solutions and that the fact that there are none with $y<10^8$ isn't exactly a good evidence for lack of solutions. First, looking modulo 4 and 5 we notice that $x, y$ must both be divisible by 10. Also note that modulo other primes there doesn't seem to be any unusual obstructions, i.e. roughly half of the values of $\{x^4+y^4+1; x, y \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\}$ are quadratic residues modulo $p$.

We then write our equation as $10^4(x^4+y^4)+1=z^2$. A random number of order $n$ has probability roughly $\tfrac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$ of being a square but here we know that it is a square modulo $10^4$, so the conditional probability is roughly $4/\sqrt{n}$. So for fixed $y$ the expected number of $x$ which would make $10^4(x^4+y^4)+1$ a perfect square is roughly
$$
\sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{25\sqrt{x^4+y^4}}\sim \frac{2}{27y},
$$
the last comparison is asymptotic for large $y$ (the exact constant is, of course, not $2/27$) but the value of the sum is somewhat smaller for small $y$.

The sum $\sum_{y=1}^\infty \frac{2}{27y}$ diverges (which suggests there are infinitely many solutions) but if you sum only over $y\leq 10^8$ the sum is still only roughly $1.4$

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just realised that on math.stackexchange much better heuristic (the Hardy-Littlewood circle method) which computes all local densities and the global one is written. (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16887/does-the-equation-x4y41-z2-have-a-non-trivial-solution) The resulting prediction is that the number of solution with positive $x, y, z < N$ should be of order $0.00448\cdot \log{N}$ so the smallest solution should appear around $10^{96}$.