# Can $x^4+y^4+1$ be a perfect power?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Recall that a perfect power has the form $x^m$ with $m,x\in\{2,3,\ldots\}$. Motivated by Fermat's result that the equation $x^4+y^4=z^2$ has no positive integer solution, here I ask the following question.

**Question 1.** Can $x^4+y^4+1$ with $x,y\in\mathbb N=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ be a perfect power?

Based on my computation, I conjecture that $x^4+y^4+1$ with $x,y\in\mathbb N$ can never be a perfect power.

**Question 2.** Can we find $x,y\in\mathbb N$ such that $x^4+y^4+1=\prod_{i=1}^kp_i^{a_i}$ for some  $a_1,\ldots,a_k\in\{2,3,\ldots\}$ and distinct primes $p_1,\ldots,p_k$?

Via a computer I find no $x^4+y^4+1$ with $x,y\in\{0,1,\ldots,8000\}$ of the form $\prod_{i=1}^kp_i^{a_i}$ with $p_1,\ldots,p_k$ distinct primes and $a_1,\ldots,a_k\in\{2,3,\ldots\}$. Perhaps, Question 2 has a negative answer. Of course, a negative answer to Question 2 implies a negative answer to Question 1.

Your comments are welcome!

Comment: Numbers as in Question 2 are known as powerful numbers. [Related question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/191889/30186), which may suggest that the answer is positive but the least example is large.

Comment: The way the question 1 is stated, with $x,y\in \{0,1,2,...\}$, $x=y=0$ fits.

Comment: @Michael OP excluded $1$ from the set of perfect powers.

Comment: Can one prove that $x^4+y^4+1$ with $x,y\in\mathbb N$ is never a square greater than one?

Comment: It has solutions in rationals like $$(\frac{95800}{414560})^4+(\frac{217519}{414560})^4+1=(\frac{422481}{414560})^4.$$

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61794/the-diophantine-eq-x4-y4-1-z2

Comment: Note that $x^4+y^4+1\equiv2{\rm\ or\ }3\bmod5$ (so is not a perfect square) unless $x$ and $y$ are both multiples of five.

Comment: Please restrict to one question per post.

Answer (score 28):

To answer question 2:
$$346^4+36788^4+1=1831575032204939793=3^3\cdot19^3\cdot179^2\cdot17569^2.$$

Comment: Cool. How did you calculate this?

Comment: I just ran through possibilities for $x$ and $y$, and then did trial division. Usually with trial division you stop when $p^2>n$, but if you're checking whether a number is powerful then you can stop when $p^5>n$, and then check whether $n$ is a perfect square or perfect cube.

Comment: One can use PARI/GP with a built-in function [ispowerful()](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/dochtml/html-stable/Arithmetic_functions.html#ispowerful).